# Listeners do not work in my Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, button, radio-button, listener

I encountered a problem when i tried to implement the onClickListener of a Button and the onCheckedChangeListener of a RadioGroup into my Fragment. None of these Listeners are working in my Fragment, the onClick()-, and onCheckedChange()-Method are not being called even though they should be.

This is my Fragment:

```
public class GeneralFragment extends Fragment {

public static Class startClass;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton r1, r2, r3;
String start;
Button confirm;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_general, container, false);
    //View view = (View)getView().inflate(getContext(), R.layout.content_general, null);

    //start = "FirstFragment";

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            System.out.println(checkedId);
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.radioButton1:
                    startClass = FirstFragment.class;
                    start = "FirstFragment";
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton2:
                    startClass = SecondFragment.class;
                    start = "SecondFragment";
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton3:
                    startClass = ThirdFragment.class;
                    start = "ThirdFragment";
                    break;
                default:
                    startClass = FirstFragment.class;
                    start = "FirstFragment";

            }
        }
    });                


    confirm = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.confirmButton);

    confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            writeToFile(start, getContext());
            System.out.println("Succesfully written!");
        }
    });        

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_general, container, false);
}

private void writeToFile(String data, Context context) {
    System.out.println("writing...");
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("settings.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}

}
```

And here is my xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">        

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/setting_two_title" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/setting_two_first" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/setting_two_second" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/setting_two_third" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/confirmButton"
    android:layout_width="147dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/setting_three" />
```

I cannot find the cause for why the click/change of the radiobutton is not being registered. I implemented the onClick()-Method this way into a different Fragment and the Button is working fine...

I really have no clue what this problem could be about and I appreciate every tip you guys can give me.

Comment: In your `onCreateView` instead of `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_general, container, false);` try putting just `return view;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_general, container, false);
```

change to

```
return view;
```

complete **onCreateView** code is here, i'm showing toast on radiobutton click

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_general, container, false);
    //View view = (View)getView().inflate(getContext(), R.layout.content_general, null);

    //start = "FirstFragment";

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            System.out.println(checkedId);
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.radioButton1:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "clicked one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton2:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "clicked two", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton3:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "clicked three", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    break;
                default:


            }
        }
    });


    confirm = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.confirmButton);

    confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            writeToFile(start, getContext());
            System.out.println("Succesfully written!");
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It really did the trick for me. Would you mind explaining why this was necessary? The way i understand it, i was giving back this exact view before as well, didn't i? Is it because the view is being changed and is supposed to return the changed value?

Comment: You're welcome, the fragment was being inflated twice, you need to inflate it once and call xml views inside fragment. You were returning second xml that's why it was causing the issue.